# Retrieve rows from a certain day but only in a certain hour

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have a query which returns all of the rows for three days ago:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 
 WHERE CONVERT(date, given_schedule)
 = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE()))
```

But I want to know limit the rows to only the hour relative to the current time. So for example, it is currently after 9:00 PM then I only want to retrieve the rows that occurred three days ago and between 9:00 and 10:00 PM.

Comment: Better yet would be to calculate the desired starting and ending date/time values and then searching for values within that range.  That would allow the query to benefit from an index on the date column.  See [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: @HABO converting to DATE is still sargable. I'm not saying convert to date is right here, but it's a common misconception that that, on its own, will defeat the index. The additional criteria of a specific hour will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT columns FROM dbo.table2
WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE, given_schedule) 
    = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
AND 
    DATEPART(HOUR, given_schedule) 
    = DATEPART(HOUR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

To address @Habo's point, you could also do:

```
DECLARE @s SMALLDATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

SET @s = DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, @s), @s));

SELECT columns FROM dbo.table2
  WHERE given_schedule >= @s
  AND given_schedule < DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @s);
```

This is, of course, most useful if there is actually an index with `given_schedule` as the leading column.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DATEDIFF function and pass in hour as the datepart argument.

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, GETDATE(), given_schedule,) BETWEEN 0 AND 1
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - you are correct, I over-simplified my example.